# PySpark accumulator that computes maximum value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator

What if we need to have value of accumulator set to be just max number out of all values returned by all task/nodes?

Example :

- accumulator a

  - node1 sets:5
  - node2 sets:6
  - node3 sets:4

As 6 is larger than 4, the final value of accumulator should be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define an `AccumulatorParam` like this one:

```py
from pyspark import AccumulatorParam

class MaxAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, initialValue):
        return initialValue
    def addInPlace(self, v1, v2):
        return max(v1, v2)
```

which can be use as shown below:

```py
acc = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(float("-inf"), MaxAccumulatorParam())
rdd = sc.parallelize([5, 6, 4], 3)

acc.value
# -inf

rdd.foreach(lambda x: acc.add(x))
acc.value
# 6
```